# Csv created with php contains also the page code

Tags: php, csv

I have got some problems to create a csv file from an array taken from the reading of a file.

```
if(isset($_POST['expcsvmail'])){
        $filemail= '../config/mail.txt';
        $mail=file($filemail, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
        $fp = fopen('exported_mails.csv', 'w+');
        foreach($mail as $df)
            fputcsv($fp, array($df));
        fclose($fp);
        header("Content-Type: text/csv");
        header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache");
        header("Content-Description: List of Emails");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=exported_mails.csv");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        readfile('exported_mails.csv');
        unlink('exported_mails.csv');
    }
```

And this is how I call it:

```
<form action="function.php" target="hidden_upload" class='formcor' method='post'>
    <input type="submit" id='expcsvmail' name='expcsvmail' value="Export Emails to CSV" class='sendval'/>
```

Now I have got two behaviour: if I call it after a refresh of a page(basically the code is inside the the calling page) the csv has got inside,after the array, all the code of the page
Otherwise if i call it with an external file I have a newline at the end ofthe file(that shouldn't be there)
 
Could someone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `exit()` at the end of your `if()` statement to stop the rest of the page being processed, or in your case, printing your PHP script as plain text to the page.